# Why does Spark SQL fail with "NumberFormatException: For input string: "1s"" with hive-site.xml from Hive?

Tags: hive, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
15/03/24 23:06:45 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1s"
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:231)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3(HiveContext.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.<init>(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.<init>(HiveContext.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.<init>(HiveContext.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:263)
```

I have copied hive-site.xml from hive conf to spark conf and I am able to run and execute sql on Hive prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the Character 's' in hive-site.xml file.

For example **Actual Property**

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay</name>
    <value>1s</value>
    <description>
      1s Expects a time value with unit (d/day, h/hour, m/min, s/sec, ms/msec, us/usec, ns/nsec), which is sec if not specified.
      Number of seconds for the client to wait between consecutive connection attempts
    </description>
  </property>
```

**Changed  Property**

```
<property>
        <name>hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>
          1s Expects a time value with unit (d/day, h/hour, m/min, s/sec, ms/msec, us/usec, ns/nsec), which is sec if not specified.
          Number of seconds for the client to wait between consecutive connection attempts
        </description>
      </property>
```

This should applicable for all the Values s/Seconds and ms/milliseconds etc. This changes should applicable only for spark.